# Failed to push to Heroku: fails on Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I push to Heroku I get the following error:

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Your app was upgraded to bundler 1.13.6.
remote:        Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 1.11.2.
remote:        
remote:        If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
remote:        Old: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        New: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
remote:        Bundler Output: Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

It works locally. Locally, `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`. `rvm list rubies` gives the following:

```
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

How to solve this issue? Is Heroku not yet accepting Ruby 2.3.1? I could of course switch back locally to version 2.3.0 but I would expect this not to be necessary?

Comment: what is your Ruby version in Gemfile.lock file?

Comment: In Gemfile.lock it says: `RUBY VERSION   ruby 2.3.0p0`. So the problem indeed seems to be there. However, when I run `bundle update` this does not change, despite that in the Gemfile I have `ruby '2.3.1'`. What should I do?

Comment: You can run `bundle install` to update Gemfile.lock

Comment: Tried it, but also then, nothing changes in Gemfile.lock and the original problem remains.

Comment: Run `gem install bundler` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `gem install bundler`, then `bundle install` to update your Ruby version in `Gemfile.lock` so that the app can use correct Ruby version specified in `Gemfile`.